# The intersection of dense subset and open subset

Tags: general-topology

Let $A$ be a dense subset of $X$, and $B$ let be a non-empty open subset of $X$.

Prove that  $A\cap B \not = \emptyset $.

if A is dense in X then $ \bar{A}=X=A\cup A'$ where $A'$ is the derived set of $A$

$B\subset X$ then $B\subset A \cup A'\to (A \cup A') \cap B \not = \emptyset \to (B \cap A') \cup (B \cap A) \not = \emptyset$

How can I conclude that   $A\cap B \not = \emptyset$ ?

Comment: What do you want to ask?

Comment: That's the definition of dense, isn't it?

Comment: If that's not your definition of dense, what is?

Comment: the last inequality means that either $B\cap A\ne\emptyset$ or $B$ contains an accumulation point of $A$, that is, a point in $A'$. What can you say about neighborhoods of points in $A'$ ?

Answer (score 1):

if B contains an accumulation point of A for example $  \{p  \}$ then B is a neighborhoods of $  \{p  \}$ and so

$(B  \setminus \{p  \})\cap A   \not=     \emptyset$ namely B contains points of  $A$ different from {p } $\to$ $B\cap A \not=     \emptyset$

I think it is exactly, thanks for the help